# Updating class variable from another class using Pool

Tags: python, class

Here is a sample code of what I want to do:

```
class myfiles:
    def __init__:
        self.input_file = ""
        self.output_file = ""

class process_files:
    def __init__(self, list_of_myfiles):
        self.myfiles_list = list_of_myfiles
        self.my_new_files = []

    def intial_work(self):
        list_of_objects = []
        for f in self.myfiles_list:
            new_files = myfiles()
            new_files.input_file = f
            list_of_objects.append(new_files)
        self.my_new_files = list_of_objects

    def update_files(self):
        # this will update the instance  output_file
        for f in self.my_new_files:
            # do some work on input file and write it to ouput new_files
            process_files.work_function(f)
        # this will not update the instance output_file
        n_cores = psutil.cpu_count()
        p = multiprocessing.Pool(n_cores)
        p.map(process_files.work_function, self.my_new_files)

    @staticmethod
    def work_function(new_file):
        # do some work on input file and update output
        new_file.output_file = "something new"
```

I have two classes the first is `myfiles` which I will use it as list of objects.
second is `process_files` which will process objects from the previous class.

```
list_of_files = ["a", "b", "c"]
myprocess =  process_files(list_of_files)
myprocess.intial_work()
myprocess.update_files()
```

In method `update_files()` if I used for loop to update the instance `myfiles.output_file` will have a value, but if I used `Pool.map myfiles.output_file` will always be empty string why?

If Pool will not work. Is there another way to run them in parallel? (multithreading or multi processing)

Comment: Because multiprocessing doesn't share state.

Comment: If you need to pass data between processes or return the results of a process, there are ways to do that (queues, pipes, managers...), but they're necessarily more complex than they would be for code executing within a single thread because they do not share an execution context. [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html) has reasonably good examples.

Comment: You may want to experiment with asyncio instead of multprocessing.